# How to copy a node with struct details in it c

Tags: c

I have a question. I have a struct with details in it. Then I have a node that contains the details of the struct. My question is, how do I copy the node to a new node with all the details in it?Can I do it like this?

```
    newNode = oldNode;
```

Or should I make it like this?

```
    newNode -> structName -> detail1 = oldNode -> structName -> detail1;
    newNode -> structName -> detail2 = oldNode -> structName -> detail2;
```

And so on. The details in struct are value type.Is there any other way? Thank you

Comment: Are `detail1` and `detail2` value or pointer types?

Comment: show sample definitions for the struct and node.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15278194/shallow-copy-and-deep-copy-in-c. It depends on what and how you want the copy.

Comment: Your first example just copies the pointer, so both pointers point to the same data. If you want a "real" copy, you'll have to do it the second way (applying the same idea to any pointers in the struct elements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your node structure has this form

```
struct node
{
  int i;
  char c;       
};
```

then to copy elements of node1 to node2, just use `node2=node1;` That will copy contents of elements of `node1` to `node2`.

However remember that only addresses get copied for pointers.
Foe example, if the structure was:

```
struct node
{
  char *c;
};
```

then using `node2=node1;` will only copy the address held by the pointer `node1.c`. Any changes made using `*node2.c` will also affect `*node1.c`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `newNode` & `oldNode` point to valid blocks in memory.

```
newNode = oldNode;
```

would mean you are pointing `newNode` to the same block where `oldNode` points to, which you don't want.

Instead, you can copy it the way you are doing by "copying" individual elements.

Or if you are copying entire "contents" of `oldNode` to `newNode`, you can use `memcpy`.

```
memcpy(newNode, oldNode, sizeof(newNode);
```